# Refactoring a complex filter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to deal with a somewhat complicated query. I've read a few methods on how I might approach this but they don't really apply here because this isn't like a complicated search form (like on a vBulletin search post form), but rather a set of routes which filter both by 'category' (unreleased, popular, latest) and by 'time' (all time, last month, last week, today)

I realize the below code is very bad. My goal was only to get it working, and refactor after. Not to mention, it doesn't even truly work because it doesn't take into account BOTH category AND time, just one or the other, but I figured I would deal with that in this thread.

Also, to make this a lot clearer for this SO code paste, I excluded the `.page(params[:page]).per(30)` from every single line, however it needs to go on all of them.

So, does anyone know how I might go about doing this? I have mulled over it for some time and am kind of stumped

```
def index
  case params[:category]
  when "latest"
    @books = Book.all.page(params[:page]).per(30)   
  when "downloads"
    @books = Book.order('downloads DESC')
  when "top100"
    @books = Book.order('downloads DESC').limit(100)
  when "unreleased"
    @books = Book.unreleased
  else
    @books = Book.all.page(params[:page]).per(30)   
  end

  case params[:time]
  when "today"
    @books = Book.days_old(1)
  when "week"
    @books = Book.days_old(7)
  when "month"
    @books = Book.days_old(30)
  when "all-time"
    @books = Book.all
  else
    @books = Book.all.page(params[:page]).per(30)   
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
# Books
get 'book/:id', to: 'books#show', as: 'book'

resources :books, only: [:index] do
  get ':category/:time(/:page)', action: 'index', on: :collection
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Move all queries to the model as scopes

   ```
   class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
     scope :downloads,  -> { order('downloads DESC') }
     scope :top100,     -> { order('downloads DESC').limit(100) }
     scope :unreleased, -> { unreleased }
     scope :today,      -> { days_old(1) }
     scope :week,       -> { days_old(7) }
     scope :month,      -> { days_old(30) }
     scope :latest,     -> { }
     scope :all_time,   -> { }
   end
   ```
2. Create auxiliary methods to filter the params and avoid unmatching data

   ```
   class BooksController < ApplicationController
     private

     def category_params
       %w(downloads top100 unreleased).include?(params[:category]) ? params[:category].to_sym : nil
     end

     def time_params
       %w(today week month latest all_time).include?(params[:time]) ? params[:time].to_sym : nil
     end
   end
   ```
3. Get rid of the `case` statement by applying the scope with the same name as the params

   ```
   def index
     query = Book.all
     query = query.send(category_params) if category_params
     query = query.send(time_params) if time_params
     @books = query.page(params[:page]).per(30)
   end
   ```

At four lines we're still within the boundaries of [Sandi Metz' guidelines](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/50655960596/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers)! :)

Comment: How would you handle 'all-time' -> :all_time ? This is a good approach, I didn't even really think of this. Will this also error out with a 500 if a path is wrong?

Comment: I didn't get the `all-time' query. Are you bypassing the pagination in that one?

Comment: Nope, all time would still be paginated

Comment: Then what's the difference between that one and the default scope?

Comment: Hmm... I suppose you're right.. Let me think about that a moment how I had this planned out

Comment: So, the route would just be `/books/latest` and that's that. There would be no further scoping to time.. although because that route is second in my params `/:category/:time(/:page)`, then I suppose I just needed a 'filler'. I suppose I would just need to redo my route for that one. *edit* nevermind, I realized it's in fact FIRST, so I will merely make (:time) optional as well... thanks!

Comment: PS I really like your website

Comment: Edited my answer to include a filter against wrong or dangerous params, as you suggested.

Comment: By the way I've never seen scopes with . periods before, I get errors until I remove them. Is that something I'm not aware of?

Comment: Nope, you're right and I'm wrong. I was typing that on Windows, and I can't think straight on Windows. I think it's the horrible font rendering or something.

Comment: One last question (thanks so much, by the way), is it quite dangerous how you had it for your first iteration, calling send() .to_sym with user-submitted data? I'm not using that now, but I'm curious for in the future.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38255/discussion-between-depa-and-tallboy)

Comment: As a side question, do you know how i use link_to so that I can get /top100/today ? when i try passing category: params[:category], it just turns them into a query string instead of /:this/:format

Answer (score 2):

In rails you can 'chain' queries, for example

```
   Book.where(:released => true).where(:popular => true)
```

is the same as

```
   Book.where(:released => true, popular => true)
```

You can use this to help with your refactoring. Here is my take on it:

```
   def index

      # Start with all books, we are going to add other filters later
      query = Book.scoped

      # Lets handle the time filter first   
      query = query.where(['created_at > ?', start_date] if start_date

      case params[:category]
      when "latest"
        query = query.order('created_at DESC')
      when "downloads"
        query = query.order('downloads DESC')
      when "top100"
        query = query.order('downloads DESC').limit(100)
      when "unreleased"
        query = query.where(:released => false)
      end

      # Finally, apply the paging
      @books = query.page(params[:page]).per(30)

end

    private

    def start_date
      case params[:time]
      when "today"
        1.day.ago 
      when "week"
        7.days.ago
      when "month"
        1.month.ago
      when "all-time"
        nil
      else
        nil
      end
    end
```

Comment: Awesome... this is great. I didn't know about `scoped`, that is perfect, and the answer to my problem